# Protobuf compilation with Go tools

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Is there a good way to integrate protobuf compiles with the `go build` command?

Comment: see [G+](https://plus.google.com/115983116618286597159/posts/7sE4HhXq15Q) for the original.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/ ?

Comment: I was kinda hoping for solution that would let me continue to use `go build`, but that may not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

[goprotobuf](https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf) "provides Go support, in the form of a library and protocol compiler plugin, for Google's protocol buffers".

The [README](https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/source/browse/README) at the [goprotobuf](https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf) library has some good info.

From https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/source/browse/README#106 :

> Consider file test.proto, containing

```
    package example;

    enum FOO { X = 17; };

    message Test {
      required string label = 1;
      optional int32 type = 2 [default=77];
      repeated int64 reps = 3;
      optional group OptionalGroup = 4 {
        required string RequiredField = 5;
      }
    }
```

> To build a package from test.proto and some other Go files, write a Makefile like this:

```
    include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)

    TARG=path/to/example
    GOFILES=\
        test.pb.go\
        other.go

    include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
    include $(GOROOT)/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/Make.protobuf
```